# Can not Capture Video Using iOS Default Camera Application. Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to launch the default iOS camera application for video recording but it does not work.

Whenever I launch the application it crashes and and does not show any error log or any other error messages.

The following code works perfectly if I set the `imagePicker.CameraCaptureMode` to `UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.Photo`.

```
var imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
imagePicker.CameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.Video;
var imagePickerDelegate = new ImagePickerDelegate(this);
imagePicker.Delegate = imagePickerDelegate;
NavigationController.PresentModalViewController(imagePicker, true);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the code for ImagePickerDelegate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work by doing this:

```
var imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
imagePicker.MediaTypes = new string[]{ UTType.Movie }; // ADD this
var imagePickerDelegate = new ImagePickerDelegate(this);
imagePicker.Delegate = imagePickerDelegate;
NavigationController.PresentModalViewController(imagePicker, true);
```

Also you can set your delegate calls like so:

```
    imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += Handle_FinishedPickingMedia;
    imagePicker.Canceled += Handle_Canceled;
```

Then create these methods:

```
    protected void Handle_FinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
    {
        //code to handle picking media
    }

    void Handle_Canceled(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imagePicker.DismissViewController(true, null);
    }
```

**Update**

In iOS 10 you need to add the permissions and provide the description as to why you are asking for the permission in the `info.plist`

see here:

[iOS 10 - Changes in asking permissions of Camera, microphone and Photo Library causing application to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498275/ios-10-changes-in-asking-permissions-of-camera-microphone-and-photo-library-c)

Comment: I've followed this, however the camera still crashes when in video mode.  The camera will successfully launch into photo mode if `new string[]{ UTType.Image, UTType.Movie }` is used, but as soon as you switch to video mode even within the camera, the app crashes.  Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to implement the permission for the microphone add the permissions string in info.plist refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498275/ios-10-changes-in-asking-permissions-of-camera-microphone-and-photo-library-c  if you still have any problem comment or ask new question and post your code.

Comment: @FahadRehman cool thanks for catching that I'll update my answer.