# Xamarin XLabs.Platform.iOS.Service.Media.MediaPicker TakeVideoAsync fails without stacktrace (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, xamarin, sigabrt, xlabs

After upgrading my device to IOS 10 several problems arose to my Xamarin IOS application.

Most of them due to the following issue

[iOS 10 - Changes in asking permissions of Camera, microphone and Photo Library causing application to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498275/ios-10-changes-in-asking-permissions-of-camera-microphone-and-photo-library-c)

In synthesis with IOS 10 upgrade some authorization requests description become mandatory (here is the documentation https://blog.xamarin.com/new-ios-10-privacy-permission-settings/)
Corrupted functionalities were:

- Access to photos through PHPhotoManager: fixed adding NSLibraryUsageDescription key to info.plist file
- Access to camera to take photo through MediaPicker TakePhotoAsync: fixed adding key NSCameraUsageDescription to info.plist file
- Access to camera to take a video through MediaPicker TakeVideoAsync: still does not work

The application crashes and the error is (the same as the error previously fixed):

> Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This ususally indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your application.

Does anyone know a fix? Does exist a key for authorize video capture?

Here is the code:

```
MediaPicker d = new MediaPicker();
VideoMediaStorageOptions opt = new VideoMediaStorageOptions();
opt.Quality = VideoQuality.Low;
return  await d.TakeVideoAsync (opt);
```

The crash happens in d.TakeVideoAsync function.

Here is the stack trace:

```
critical: 0   MyAppOS1   0x00000001000afd68 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 260
critical: 1   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000000018a3d3348 _sigtramp + 52
critical: 2   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000018a30d480 <redacted> + 100
critical: 3   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000018a30d4c8 system_set_sfi_window + 0
critical: 4   TCC                    0x000000018d54e560 <redacted> + 0
critical: 5   TCC                    0x000000018d54e45c <redacted> + 0
critical: 6   TCC                    0x000000018d55152c <redacted> + 288
critical: 7   libxpc.dylib           0x000000018a41801c <redacted> + 80
critical: 8   libxpc.dylib           0x000000018a417f8c <redacted> + 40
critical: 9   libdispatch.dylib      0x000000018a1cd1c0 <redacted> + 16
critical: 10  libdispatch.dylib      0x000000018a1dbab4 <redacted> + 732
critical: 11  libdispatch.dylib      0x000000018a1dd38c <redacted> + 572
critical: 12  libdispatch.dylib      0x000000018a1dd0ec <redacted> + 124
critical: 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000018a3d52c8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
critical: 14  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000018a3d4db4 start_wqthread + 4
critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Tx Z

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace?

Comment: I added the stack trace

Comment: Nothing throws before that?

Comment: Nothing, and the exception cannot be catched because TakeVideoAsync is a native function