# Is empty NSCameraUsageDescription accepted?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, info.plist, ios-permissions

If your app uses camera, you have to set `NSCameraUsageDescription` in `InfoPlist.strings`. But what if I don't want to use any custom message? Is it accepted to set empty `empty NSCameraUsageDescription` like this:

```
NSCameraUsageDescription = "";
```

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW24) say a bit strange about this:
`If your app attempts to access the device’s camera without a corresponding purpose string, your app exits`.
What is "exits"? Will my app rejected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
NSCameraUsageDescription = "";
```

Without any message, you just need to put the key in the plist. Also in the doc

> If your app attempts to access the device’s camera without a
>   corresponding purpose string, your app exits.

They mentioned exits, it means the app will get closed if you don't put that string but i have checked it now, and the popup is showing without any message just the title.

Comment: But it will get rejected.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not accepted .

iOS already required permissions to access microphone, camera, and media library earlier (iOS6, iOS7), but since iOS10 the apps will crash if you don't provide the description why you are asking for the permission.

from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38498347/3901620

Comment: No, I meant `InfoPlist.strings`, not Info.plist. If you will try use empty string, I will not get crash

Comment: is camera open with this string in ios 10 ?

Comment: In debug everything works. @Rajat wrote, he also checked this