# PhoneGap camera is not working on ios 10

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a button that onclick class the function getImage(); and it crashes when I call it on my iphone 7 plus that has ios 10. Can someone please tell me why this is happening and give me the right code for to stop this. Here is the code I have as of now that used to work and stil works on older ios and android.

navigator.camera.getPicture function crashes on ios 10 device.

```
    function getImage() {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, 
            function(message) {
                alert('get picture failed');
            }, {
                quality: 80, 
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                correctOrientation : true,
                allowEdit: true
                }
        );

    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {



        //function sendPhoto(filetype){

            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            //get file name
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

            //Check if the device is android or not and if it is use the folowing code
            var devicePlatform = device.platform;


            if(devicePlatform == "Android"){                    
                //check file extension
                options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+".jpeg";






            }   



            var params = new Object();

            params.value1 =  "Babatunde";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "uploadUserPhoto.php", win, fail, options);

        //Part of the commment out function sendPhoto
        //}
   }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        alert(r.response);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    }
```

Comment: Did you add permission for camera access in `info.plist` file ? Refer this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38498347/6449750

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this permission in Info.plist for iOS 10

> Camera :

Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use

> Photo :

Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use

Answer (score 0):

Reason why app crashes on `iOS10` and not on versions earlier is because you need to add permissions for Camera and Album. You need to add permissions to your `info.plist`

Photo :

```
Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description    
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use
```

Camera :

```
Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description   
Value   :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use
```

For list of keys you need to specify in your info.plist is in this [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)