# This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data

Tags: ios, privacy, xcode8-beta2

I have added privacy settings in `info.plist` still it crashes. I don't why.

[image: Here is my plist screenshot.]

It says:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain
>   an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.

**Please note that I have already tried re-installing app. I am using iOS 10 Device no simulator.**

Comment: @BhavinRamani : Duede read the full question

Comment: Reset the simulator. Uninstalling wont work either.

Comment: @Sandeep-Systematix : I am running app in device. No simulator

Comment: If its the case then you should put question rightly and not edit too frequently.

Comment: can you change the description to something more appropiate , and also do check out this answer if it helps you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39608340/3755838

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset the simulator and run again. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` from `plist` then run your application in device. Then delete the application from device. then add `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` in `plist` and give `description` to it(don't keep it empty, write some description!) and install again in device!