# Xamarin iOS Crash with Twilio Client

Tags: twilio

I have a crash in a Xamarin app that is using the Twilio Client Component.  I use the "Getting Started" code to make a simple app that makes a phone call out when I click a button.  From the crash log I see a reference to "**CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION**" in the call stack.  I don't know what that could be as I have "Audio and Airplay" and "Voice over IP" check in background modes in my apps plist file.

The odd thing in in simulator it works perfect, the crash only occurs when I run the app on the iPhone.  My phone is running ios 10.2.  I am including the code and the crash log.  Please help as this crash occurs exactly the same way in an app I am building for work so I really need to solve it and I am at my wits end.

```
    using System;
    using UIKit;
    using Foundation;
    using TwilioClient.iOS;

    namespace twiliotest
    {
       public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
       {
          TCDevice _device;
          TCConnection _connection;

          protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
         {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization         logic.
         }

         public override void ViewDidLoad()
         {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            string sLink = "https://www.myserver.com/captok.php";
            var url = new NSUrl(sLink);
            var data = NSData.FromUrl(url);
            var token = data.ToString();

            // Create a new TCDevice object passing in the token.
            _device = new TCDevice(token, null);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        }

        partial void ButtonCall_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            if (_connection == null || _connection.State == TCConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                var param = new TCConnectionParameters
                {
                    From = "12125551234",
                    To = "12125554321"
                };
                _connection = _device.Connect(param, null);
            }
            else {
                _connection.Disconnect();
            }           
        }

        void SetupDeviceEvents()
        {
            if (_device != null)
            {
                _device.ReceivedIncomingConnection += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    _connection = e.Connection;
                    _connection.Accept();
                };
            }
        }

       }
    }
```

Here is the crash log.  Note the crash is in thread 7.

```
    Incident Identifier: FA61C36F-110A-44DF-A862-FD7C37859D8E
    CrashReporter Key:   dc2811c1cf8685a6f8963c39740ec1af0fb4e080
    Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
    Process:             twiliotest [7846]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/412D52E2-9ECB-4C01-B984-AB2820FBBFB0/twiliotest.app/twiliotest
    Identifier:          com.davidkbowers.twiliotest
    Version:             1.0 (1.0)
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Role:                Foreground
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]
    Coalition:           com.davidkbowers.twiliotest [1855]


    Date/Time:           2017-01-04 18:50:06.7079 -0500
    Launch Time:         2017-01-04 18:50:00.8968 -0500
    OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.2 (14C92)
    Report Version:      104

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    Triggered by Thread:  7

    Application Specific Information:
    abort() called

    Filtered syslog:
    None found

    Thread 0 name:  tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c5188 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c4ff8 mach_msg + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832c25d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832c01ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001831ee2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
    5   GraphicsServices                0x0000000184ca2198 GSEventRunModal + 180
    6   UIKit                           0x00000001892357fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
    7   UIKit                           0x0000000189230534 UIApplicationMain + 208
    8   twiliotest                      0x000000010047cd04 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr (/<unknown>:1)
    9   twiliotest                      0x0000000100462a9c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr (UIApplication.cs:79)
    10  twiliotest                      0x0000000100462a5c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string (UIApplication.cs:63)
    11  twiliotest                      0x0000000100438e04 twiliotest_Application_Main_string__ (Main.cs:12)
    12  twiliotest                      0x000000010059bb64 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
    13  twiliotest                      0x000000010032ee28 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:2524)
    14  twiliotest                      0x000000010039d1e8 do_runtime_invoke (object.c:2809)
    15  twiliotest                      0x000000010039f7cc mono_runtime_exec_main (object.c:4585)
    16  twiliotest                      0x000000010039f3e8 mono_runtime_run_main (object.c:4134)
    17  twiliotest                      0x0000000100314050 mono_jit_exec (driver.g.c:1048)
    18  twiliotest                      0x0000000100438bd0 xamarin_main (monotouch-main.m:487)
    19  twiliotest                      0x00000001005ec148 main (main.arm64.m:45)
    20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001821d15b8 start + 4

    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822e3a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a7344 _pthread_wqthread + 1452
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d8c start_wqthread + 4

    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d88 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.twilio.TCCommandHandler.commandQ
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c5188 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c4ff8 mach_msg + 72
    2   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000186313c90 AUIOClient_Initialize + 228
    3   AudioToolbox                    0x00000001861a1864 AURemoteIO::Initialize() + 1328
    4   AudioToolbox                    0x000000018649c3b0 AUBase::DoInitialize() + 48
    5   AudioToolbox                    0x00000001864a4888 AUMethodInitialize(void*) + 76
    6   twiliotest                      0x00000001002251d8 create_audio_unit (coreaudio_dev.m:1507)
    7   twiliotest                      0x0000000100224c7c ca_factory_create_stream (coreaudio_dev.m:1599)
    8   twiliotest                      0x0000000100233d4c twilio_pjmedia_aud_stream_create (audiodev.c:790)
    9   twiliotest                      0x00000001002319d4 twilio_pjmedia_snd_port_create2 (sound_port.c:261)
    10  twiliotest                      0x0000000100241cec open_snd_dev (pjsua_aud.c:1715)
    11  twiliotest                      0x00000001002422d8 twilio_pjsua_set_snd_dev (pjsua_aud.c:1974)
    12  twiliotest                      0x0000000100213998 twilio_pjsua_call_make_call (pjsua_call.c:645)
    13  twiliotest                      0x00000001001f7090 -[TCCall makeCall] (TCCall.m:51)
    14  twiliotest                      0x00000001001e04a4 -[TCMakeCallCommand run] (TCCommands.m:215)
    15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018219e1fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018219e1bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001821ac3dc _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
    18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001821a19a4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
    19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001821ac8d8 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 360
    20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001821ae34c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
    21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001821ae0ac _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
    22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a72a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d8c start_wqthread + 4

    Thread 4 name:  SGen worker
    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822e2e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a89c0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
    2   twiliotest                      0x00000001003fa544 thread_func (mono-os-mutex.h:108)
    3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9850 _pthread_body + 240
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9760 _pthread_body + 0
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d94 thread_start + 4

    Thread 5 name:  Finalizer
    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c51c4 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
    1   twiliotest                      0x00000001003613f8 finalizer_thread (mono-os-semaphore.h:73)
    2   twiliotest                      0x00000001003ce664 start_wrapper (threads.c:740)
    3   twiliotest                      0x000000010041efbc inner_start_thread (mono-threads-posix.c:92)
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9850 _pthread_body + 240
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9760 _pthread_body + 0
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d94 thread_start + 4

    Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c5188 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c4ff8 mach_msg + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832c25d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832c01ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001831ee2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
    5   Foundation                      0x0000000183d2b26c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
    6   Foundation                      0x0000000183d4bdd0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
    7   UIKit                           0x0000000189ba9c38 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
    8   Foundation                      0x0000000183e28e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9850 _pthread_body + 240
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9760 _pthread_body + 0
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d94 thread_start + 4

    Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
    Thread 7 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822e3014 __pthread_kill + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823ab450 pthread_kill + 112
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182257400 abort + 140
    3   twiliotest                      0x0000000100320aa0 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2420)
    4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001823a5348 _sigtramp + 52
    5   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822de49c abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
    6   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822de4c8 system_set_sfi_window + 0
    7   TCC                             0x0000000185552328 __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke_2.80 + 0
    8   TCC                             0x0000000185552224 __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 0
    9   TCC                             0x0000000185555330 __tccd_send_block_invoke + 348
    10  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001823e6fcc _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 80
    11  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001823e6f3c _xpc_connection_call_reply + 40
    12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018219e1bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001821aca4c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 732
    14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001821ae34c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
    15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001821ae0ac _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a72a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d8c start_wqthread + 4

    Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
    Thread 8:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c5188 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c4ff8 mach_msg + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832c25d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832c01ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001831ee2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
    5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001839f38f0 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 336
    6   Foundation                      0x0000000183e28e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9850 _pthread_body + 240
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9760 _pthread_body + 0
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d94 thread_start + 4

    Thread 9:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822e3314 __semwait_signal + 8
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018220125c nanosleep + 212
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018220117c usleep + 64
    3   twiliotest                      0x000000010021b694 twilio_pj_thread_sleep (os_core_unix.c:780)
    4   twiliotest                      0x00000001002902f8 twilio_pj_ioqueue_poll (ioqueue_select.c:862)
    5   twiliotest                      0x000000010028d608 worker_proc (endpoint.c:332)
    6   twiliotest                      0x000000010021b4b0 thread_main (os_core_unix.c:531)
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9850 _pthread_body + 240
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9760 _pthread_body + 0
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d94 thread_start + 4

    Thread 10:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822e323c __select + 8
    1   twiliotest                      0x000000010024ead4 twilio_pj_sock_select (sock_select.c:110)
    2   twiliotest                      0x0000000100290044 twilio_pj_ioqueue_poll (ioqueue_select.c:882)
    3   twiliotest                      0x000000010027d98c twilio_pjsip_endpt_handle_events2 (sip_endpoint.c:741)
    4   twiliotest                      0x0000000100221f64 twilio_pjsua_handle_events (pjsua_core.c:1837)
    5   twiliotest                      0x0000000100221a98 worker_thread (pjsua_core.c:695)
    6   twiliotest                      0x000000010021b4b0 thread_main (os_core_unix.c:531)
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9850 _pthread_body + 240
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9760 _pthread_body + 0
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d94 thread_start + 4

    Thread 11 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
    Thread 11:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c5188 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c4ff8 mach_msg + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832c25d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832c01ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001831ee2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
    5   AVFAudio                        0x000000019ce83d24 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
    6   AVFAudio                        0x000000019cea9d9c CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9850 _pthread_body + 240
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9760 _pthread_body + 0
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d94 thread_start + 4

    Thread 12:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001822c51dc semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001821b0770 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 112
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001821af808 _dispatch_worker_thread + 268
    3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9850 _pthread_body + 240
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a9760 _pthread_body + 0
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d94 thread_start + 4

    Thread 13:
    0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001823a6d88 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 7 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
        x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2:                 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000015be197a0
        x4: 0x000000000000001b   x5: 0x000000016e359b00   x6: 0x0000000000000034   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
        x8: 0x000000000c000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000003dd5  x11: 0x00000001ab196da3
       x12: 0x00000001ab196da3  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
       x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
       x20: 0x000000016e35b000  x21: 0x000000010062d6b7  x22: 0x000000010062d77e  x23: 0xc698a6e613ac0034
       x24: 0x000000016e359ee8  x25: 0x000000010062d731  x26: 0x000000015c8c0e78  x27: 0x0000000000000004
       x28: 0xffffffffffffffff   fp: 0x000000016e359e80   lr: 0x00000001823ab450
        sp: 0x000000016e359e60   pc: 0x00000001822e3014 cpsr: 0x00000000

    Binary Images:
    0x1000fc000 - 0x1006ebfff twiliotest arm64          <24d1aa9aa95d3911b2709a7a36f9a785> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/412D52E2-9ECB-4C01-B984-AB2820FBBFB0/twiliotest.app/twiliotest
```

0x100898000 - 0x1008c7fff dyld arm64   /usr/lib/dyld

Remainder deleted due to space considerations...

EOF

Please let me know if there is anything else I need to post.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are using the latest iOS voice SDK 2.0 https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/ios. The Xamarin component you are using might be based on deprecated version (Twilio iOS Client SDK). The new version is Programmable Voice iOS SDK which does support iOS 10.

Details in the [changelog](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/ios/changelog).

Answer (score 0):

Apps targeting iOS 10+ will crash if the required permissions string is missing.

In the case of Twilio, it needs access to the phone's microphone, so your app will need to ask the user for microphone usage permission.

You can do this by editing the Info.plist file of your app. Add this code `<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>My app needs to use the microphone.</string>` within the `<dict> ... </dict>` section.

See [iOS 10 - Changes in asking permissions of Camera, microphone and Photo Library causing application to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498275/ios-10-changes-in-asking-permissions-of-camera-microphone-and-photo-library-c) and https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html for more details.