# App upload with Application loader

Tags: ios

I have tried to upload app using Application Loader on Mac.
An upload is succeed however there is not any app in iTunes Connect in my app.
Version and SkuID and AppleID is match between app information in iTunes Connect and the app which is uploaded using Application Loader.

so causing of that, I cannot complete 'submit for review'.
Could you help me please?
Thank you for any further help.

[succeed upload app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znNxn.jpg)

[there is not appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHaDP.png)

Comment: what version of xcode are you using?

Comment: Hi Daniel, xcode version is 5.1 and application loader's is version 3.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use such an old version of XCode? How long have you had to wait? I know after I've uploaded apps it's taken 30+ minutes sometimes to process. Although yesterday I had to submit an app twice, because after the first time it just disappeared for no reason.

Comment: Hi Pierce,
Because our previous developer was using that XCode.

Comment: I will wait for 30 minutes....

Comment: nothing change! any idea please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to use XCode 5.1.

When I use XCode 6.2, everything went thought well.

Use Application Loader with XCode after 6.

Thank you for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Binary on iTunes connect is corrupted. To resolve this,  check your binary is compatible with Ios 10. 
Please use this link for permission in plist file then try to upload new build with new build version.

[iOS 10 - Changes in asking permissions of Camera, microphone and Photo Library causing application to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498275/ios-10-changes-in-asking-permissions-of-camera-microphone-and-photo-library-c)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY8RG.png

If it's not resolved , please contact iTunes connect support to find out the exact reason. They will reply on mailbox with exact reason of binary corruption. Then needful actions to resolve issue.
https://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus
[image: Apple contact us.]

Comment: Hi Ankit,
Thank you for your help. 
My problem is to upload *.ipa file using Application loader when I publish it.
Is it related to your idea ??

Comment: @takeo-nishioka Yes ! It's related. Same things was happened with me many times. Apple replied me within 3 hours. Last time they replied me after 3 days. They told me to enter Privacy Permission in plist for ios 10 compatible.

Comment: You should try upload ipa with permission in plist file.

Comment: Please use Xcode 6 or later to upload. Actually the binary compiled with xcode version 5.1 may be corrupted.