# Integrating Google Drive -Missing Info.plist key

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

In my application i integrated new Google drive Api and done code for login and upload file to Google drive. After successfully upload file. I build the app and upload to Test flight, but the build not uploaded in the test flight. Its shows this **Error**

> **Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.**

**Need push notification entitlement.**

But in my application not using camera and push notification.

Referred this link to integrate google drive in my app. 
[iOS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Missing Info.plist key ... NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611987/how-to-resolve-missing-info-plist-key-nsphotolibraryusagedescription)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for more than a week. And finally I found the solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/UmeVUDrcDaw/HIXR0kjUAgAJ. check this url hope this will help you.