# Selecting "camera" causes Terminated due to signal 9

Tags: ios, swift, memory, crash, uiimagepickercontroller

In iOS Swift 3.1 I'm trying to access the camera, the same way I have done successfully in other apps. However, in this one particular app, it always crashes on the `self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)` line. The message in the console is `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9`. Does this usually signal a memory related error?

```
@IBAction func onChooseImageClick(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum){

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        //Create the AlertController and add Its action like button in Actionsheet
        let actionSheetControllerForImage: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Please select", message: "Option to select", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let cancelActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in
            print("Cancel")
        }
        actionSheetControllerForImage.addAction(cancelActionButton)

        let cameraActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default)
        { action -> Void in
            print("Camera")
            if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)) {
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
                let mediaTypes:[String] = [kUTTypeImage as String]
                imagePicker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

                self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "error", message: "Camera not found!", preferredStyle: .alert)

                let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) { action in
                    // ...
                }
                alertController.addAction(OKAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true)
            }
        }
        actionSheetControllerForImage.addAction(cameraActionButton)

        let galleryActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Image Gallery", style: .default)
        { action -> Void in
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        actionSheetControllerForImage.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        actionSheetControllerForImage.addAction(galleryActionButton)
   ===> self.present(actionSheetControllerForImage, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a string in your plist file that explains why your app need permission to use the camera. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498275/ios-10-changes-in-asking-permissions-of-camera-microphone-and-photo-library-c for details about these strings.

Comment: @GaryMakin I thought I had that in my plist, but I guess I was looking at the "Library" one instead. That fixed the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: @GaryMakin, did you want to include your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a string in your plist file that explains why your app need permission to use the camera. There's a great summary of these strings in the question at [iOS 10 - Changes in asking permissions of Camera, microphone and Photo Library causing application to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38498275/968577), with a list you can copy from in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40734360/968577

Without the required strings, your app will crash in this manner. However, the console output will explain what the problem is.

Comment: I just added exit(0) when i opened the camera settings. It's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try like this i hope it would be helpful!!
Add these two points in info.plist first

1. Privacy - Camera Usage Description
2. Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

Add these two delegates in your class file

1. UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
2. UINavigationControllerDelegate

   ```
    @IBAction func onclickImageAction(_ sender: Any){

   print("onclickImageAction method called here")
   let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
   imagePicker.delegate = self
   imagePicker.isEditing = false

   let actionSheet =  UIAlertController(title: "Select Profile Photo", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

   let libButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Select photo from library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){ (libSelected) in
       print("library selected")


       imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
       self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   actionSheet.addAction(libButton)
   let cameraButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a picture", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (camSelected) in

       if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera))
       {
           imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
           self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
       else
       {
           actionSheet.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
           let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There is no camera available", preferredStyle: .alert)
           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in

               alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
           }))

       }

   }
   actionSheet.addAction(cameraButton)
   let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { (cancelSelected) in

       print("cancel selected")

   }
   actionSheet.addAction(cancelButton)
   let albumButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Saved Album", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (albumSelected) in

       print("Album selected")

       imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum
       self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

   }
   actionSheet.addAction(albumButton)
   self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion:nil)
   }
   ```

Implement these delegate method

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{if let PickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        {
            yourimageview.image = PickedImage
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added exit(0) when i opened the camera settings. It's working fine