# Photo library's image is not shown

Tags: ios, swift

Photo library's image is not shown.
My app is like
[my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjUNt.png)

My goal in this app is 2 points.First thing is when I put "PhotoSelect" button,I can select photo library's image.Second thing is to be shown the library's image in UIImageView but this cannot be done.I can access photo library, select picture but the picture is not shown.
PhotoController is

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class PhotoController:UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func PhotoSelect(_ sender: Any) {
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func PhotoSend(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    private func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])

    {
        myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //myImageUploadRequest()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

  }
```

I think connection is ok, so necessary code is not in PhotoController,right?But I do not know the code to add this PhotoController.How can fix this?

Comment: is your application crush ?

Comment: i do not know crush or not

Comment: then run your code and check it

Comment: I already write my code in my question & check it

Comment: are you working on swift 3.0 ?

Comment: Have a look at Apple's documentation, is your source type available?: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html Furthermore make sure you got the privacy settings in your App's Info.plist configured: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498275/ios-10-changes-in-asking-permissions-of-camera-microphone-and-photo-library-c

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya please don't edit the original question to answer it. Post an answer or a comment instead. I reverted your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this delegate method is deprecated in Swift 3.1, use this method instead.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        self.myImageView.image = image
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```