# TestFlight Processing status

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

After uploading a new version of the application in **TestFlight**, the application has status **Processing** and after several minutes the assembly disappears from the list.

Previously, there was no such problem, what could be the reason?

Comment: For how long have you been waiting in total now?

Comment: I waiting 2 days. I upload several versions and have not errors.

Comment: You would have received an email if processing gets failed. If you're sure that everything is fine at your end, give 1 more try. Processing doesn't take more than an hr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the mailbox you will get a mail from Apple for that reason and if you still not got any mail so please check plist and permission in that make sure you have included all required permissions in plist.

Also, you can refer below answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498347

If you did all these steps then you should wait for some time. Build automatically in testflight.

Do let me know if it helps.

Comment: It was necessary to add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in info.plist