# App disappeared in TestFlight - App Store Connect

Tags: ios

The application disappeared from TestFlight and Activity after being successfully delivered by Transporter.

Comment: How can it disappear automatically? Have you checked App Store Connect?

Comment: Yes, I am monitoring the App Store Connect. The Build remained on the platform for about 25 minutes with status "PROCESSING ...", and then disappeared.

Comment: Check you email then, they would have sent you something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TestFlight Processing status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500572/testflight-processing-status)