# iOS10 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum TCC__CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, plist

I want to create and save a `UIImage` in iOS 10. I can create it either by taking a `UIView` snapshot or using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` (*shown below*).

```
- (UIView *)createIcon
{
    UIGraphicsImageRenderer *renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)];

    UIImage *image = [renderer imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext * _Nonnull context) {
        [[UIColor darkGrayColor] setStroke];
        [context strokeRect:renderer.format.bounds];
        [[UIColor colorWithRed:158/255.0 green:215/255.0 blue:245/255.0 alpha:0.5] setFill];
        [context fillRect:CGRectMake(30, 30, 140, 140)];
        [[UIColor colorWithRed:243/255.0 green:122/255.0 blue:216/255.0 alpha:0.3] setFill];
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context.CGContext, CGRectMake(30, 30, 120, 120));
    }];

    UIImageView *showImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

    return showImage;
}
```

However, when I try to save using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` by including the second last statement, Xcode goes into Debug with the following error report

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #5, queue = 'com.apple.root.default-qos', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x00000001101611a6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload + 10
    frame #1: 0x000000011015b86e libsystem_kernel.dylib`abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 89
    frame #2: 0x000000011015b89b libsystem_kernel.dylib`abort_with_payload + 9
    frame #3: 0x0000000108ab3af7 TCC`__CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 182
    frame #4: 0x0000000108ab3a41 TCC`__TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke.77 + 665
    frame #5: 0x0000000108ab7273 TCC`__tccd_send_block_invoke + 274
```

So even though I didn’t use a camera to create the image, saving it to the photo album is a violation of privacy (*hiss, boo*)! I know it is possible to set up [privacy keys in the plist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38498347/2348597) but is there a more sensible alternative?

**CLARIFICATION**

I hope to use rendered images (or view snapshots) as assets in the app. So instead of *is there a more sensible alternative ?*

perhaps I should have asked

is there an alternative place to save images (i.e. as PNG or JPG files) so privacy is not an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save any UIImage to the photo album but first you must ask the user for permission to do as this as it is indeed a privacy issue.  If they don't give you access then you can't save the image at all.

The most sensible approach is to add the required privacy key to the info.plist.

This is the info.plist xml definition although it's easier to add the keys in the property list:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Message requesting the ability to add to the photo library</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Message requestion the ability to access the photo library</string>
```

If you add these then when you first try to access or add to the photo library a popup will display with your message allowing the user to decide if they want your app to have access.

One good reason to put it in the info.plist file is that all the requests for access are then in a single easily visible place instead of somewhere random in your project.

**EDIT**

Here is how to save the image in documents which does not raise and privacy issues:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; //Add the file name
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
```

If you want a jpg instead of a png use this instead:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9); // Use whatever compression ratio you want instead of 0.9
```

Comment: Adding `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` isn't "the most sensible approach", it's the only approach. You must add that key if you wish to use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

Comment: I should have made it clearer when I said the most sensible approach I meant that's the one that you should go for.  I know for some access (like accessing the image library) you can ask for it in the code instead of updating the info.plist but I'm not sure this is true for adding to the image library.

Comment: @rmaddy, and UpholderOfTruth, a clarification. I hope to use the rendered images (or view snapshots) as assets in the app. That’s why I questioned why there is a privacy issue.

Comment: @Greg iOS has always required apps to get permission to read from a user's photo library. Now, as of iOS 11, you also need (different) permission to add to the user's photo library.

Comment: @Greg if it's just a case of saving the image somewhere other than the photo library I will update my answer to show how to save the image in the documents folder for the app.

Comment: Thanks, this gets to the point I tried to make. I had come to realise that the user's photo library is not where such images belong. This is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Follow this code:**

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>
```

## pragma mark - Save Image in photo album

```
- (void)addImageToCameraRoll:(UIImage *)image {
NSString *albumName = @"Your app name";

void (^saveBlock)(PHAssetCollection *assetCollection) = ^void(PHAssetCollection *assetCollection) {
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *assetCollectionChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:assetCollection];
        [assetCollectionChangeRequest addAssets:@[[assetChangeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset]]];

    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Error creating asset: %@", error);
        }
    }];
};

PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localizedTitle = %@", albumName];
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny options:fetchOptions];
if (fetchResult.count > 0) {
    saveBlock(fetchResult.firstObject);
} else {
    __block PHObjectPlaceholder *albumPlaceholder;
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle:albumName];
        albumPlaceholder = changeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection;

    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[albumPlaceholder.localIdentifier] options:nil];
            if (fetchResult.count > 0) {
                saveBlock(fetchResult.firstObject);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error creating album: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
}
```

Comment: kalpesh, thanks. Can the image assets be added to a folder other than a shared photo library ? (see my clarification in response to comments above)

Comment: Yes, you shared photo library.