# Permission for camera not working in android app React Native

Tags: react-native

No message is being prompted. It just denies the permission. I have also made same, the targetedSdk version and compilesdk version.

I've made same, the targetedSdk version and compilesdk version.

My function on 'Request' Button:

```
try {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
    {
      'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
      'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
                 'so you can take awesome pictures.'
    }
  )
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    alert("You can use the camera")
  } else if (PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.DENIED){
    console.log("Camera permission denied")
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err)
}
```

I expect a prompt message and by tapping 'Yes', it must grant the permission but no prompt is shown.

Comment: what's your compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion? I think that it should not matter as long as the targetSdkVersion is above 23

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for the same? I am facing the same issue with targetSdkVersion = 29.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to also add in the permissions to the Manifest file for Android or the pList in iOS.

For Android:

Add this to your Manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera

For iOS

Take a look here: [iOS 10 - Changes in asking permissions of Camera, microphone and Photo Library causing application to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498275/ios-10-changes-in-asking-permissions-of-camera-microphone-and-photo-library-c)

Comment: I have added these permissions. But still, it is not prompting and returns granted on app install