# Can someone please tell me why my apps crashes when I press the cam button

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I had a class that i chose to remove and after that my add keeps crashing.

Below is what is in the button

```
@IBAction func cameraButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagePickerController = ImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.imageLimit = 1
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func wrapperDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {

    }
    func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
        guard let image = images.first else {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }


   if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage{
            selectedImage = image
            photo.image = image
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
//            dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
//                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Camera", sender: nil)
//            })
        }
```

if I uncomment the what is above my app crashes when i try to choose from the library

more

```
//    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
//        if segue.identifier == "filter_segue" {
//            let filterVC = segue.destination as! FilterViewController
//            filterVC.selectedImage = self.selectedImage
//            filterVC.delegate = self
//        }
   // }

//extension CameraViewController: FilterViewControllerDelegate {
//    func updatePhoto(image: UIImage) {
//        self.photo.image = image
//        self.selectedImage = image
//    }
//}
```

Comment: would you explain what are you trying to do ? and which part of the code are you trying to uncomment ?

Comment: I am still learning. I am playing around with a tutorial that i am currently working on and I removed one of the segues. What I want to do is to access my camera and place it in the app. But as soon as I open it it crashes. I will add more code that I have uncommented. I just want to know why and what to do about it. Thanks

Comment: have you added the permission in your .plist file ?

Comment: also just to be sure, you are running your app on device , right ?

Comment: yes i am running it there

Comment: camera permission : NSCameraUsageDescription 
you should add it to the .plist file

Comment: hmm the plist. What do I add there again?

Comment: add `NSCameraUsageDescription` to info.plist

Comment: this might help :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498275/ios-10-changes-in-asking-permissions-of-camera-microphone-and-photo-library-c

Comment: do I simply add the row and paste it there?

Comment: yeah, when you are typing it in a new row , it will auto complete it for you. then you can add a custom message to show for asking permission alert view in front of it.

Comment: fixed ? I posted as answer below you can mark it as answer if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crashes could be simply because of these:

- not having required permission added to the info.plist ( in this case you will get message in the log that permission is missing in .plist file.
- object are not connected to the correct IBOutlet ( in this case the circle beside the IBOutlet in files would be empty which means its not connected to any object.)

for your case permission is missing in your info.plist. you should add `NSCameraUsageDescription` and the value is a string which will be shown on permission dialog when asks user the permission to open camera . it will be like this:

[image]